# Desired Json Output Java

Tags: java, mysql, json

I am new to Java annd Json. I wish to ask that how do I get the following Json output.

```
{
"AppData": {
    "status": "****",
    "message": [
        ""
    ]
},
"Data": {
    "token": "****"
}
```

}

I using the following code.
Code for retrieving data from database, import into HashMap and retrieve from HashMap.

```
HashMap<AppDataRequest, AppData> appdatas = new HashMap<AppDataRequest, AppData>();

static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://****:3306/****";

static final String USER = "****";
static final String PASS = "****";

public AppDataService(){
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stat = null;
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
        stat = conn.createStatement();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM testdata";
        ResultSet resu = stat.executeQuery(sql);
        while(resu.next()){
            int id = resu.getInt("app_id");
            String email = resu.getString("email");
            String password = resu.getString("password");
            String token = resu.getString("token");
            appdatas.put(new AppDataRequest(id, email, password), new AppData(" ", "success", token));
        }
        resu.close();
        stat.close();
        conn.close();
    }
    catch(SQLException se){
        se.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        try{
            if(stat!=null){
                stat.close();
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException se2){

        }
        try{
            if(conn!=null){
                conn.close();
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException se3){
            se3.printStackTrace();
        }
    }       
}

public AppData getSAppData(int id, String email, String password){
    return appdatas.get(new AppDataRequest (id, email, password));
}
```

Code for POST

```
@POST
@Path("/appdatas")
public AppData getSAppData(AppDataRequest adr) {
    AppData appdata = ads.getSAppData(adr.getId(), adr.getEmail(), adr.getPassword());
    if(appdata == null){
        throw new DataNotFoundException(" ");
    }
    return appdata;
}
```

And my output in Postman is

```
{
  "message": "****",
  "status": "****",
  "token": "****"
}
```

I wish to get the output as shown in the Json output at top. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Your output is the Json representation of the data you return.

The following method returns an object of type `AppData` which is the value of your `appdatas` map.

```
public AppData getSAppData(int id, String email, String password){
    return appdatas.get(new AppDataRequest (id, email, password));
}
```

If you want to change the output, then return the appropriate data, the key (`AppDataRequest`) object and the value (`AppData`) object.